# What would an American "king" or "queen" be called. Assume those titles are too offensive for American senses

Tags: united-states

This is purely hypothetical, of course, but here's my quick scenario:

Assume the people of the United States voted to install a `royal` family, one that had no power, and was purely ceremonial. But, according to true American sensibilities, this family cannot use the titles "king," "queen," or "emperor."

What suite of titles could be appended to such a family? Something inoffensive, yet still evincing a sense of wonder. ("power" is not the right word). Something unrelated to English titles, is what I'm thinking. And titles that avoid sycophantic-type treatment. Any thoughts?

Added clarity: The current government structure of the US remains the same. There is no transfer of power to this new royal family. They are created within the US Constitution (by amendment), but exist within the current political ecosystem.

Comment: What is the name of X is always opinion based.

Comment: And I'm asking for opinions

Comment: Sorry, here we prefer questions which can be answered in a measurable way. Opinions are not such. If possible rework your question to fit our standards.

Comment: *eye roll* - do what you must, but the answer below, the one starting with `introducing royalty`, shows how this question can be answered in a measurable way

Comment: yes, and that only answer contains 7 different options...

Comment: @papelr, we apologize, but Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  Seeking opinions is *exactly* what they don't want anybody doing.  This is why one of the reasons to close a question is because it's primarily opinion-based. Read though [this specific Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand the limitations Stack Exchange has asked everyone to live with.  Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely opinion based. Sure, we còuld call him the Grand Poobah. America has already had kings (HM George III being the last royal king), and Washington's coronation at Philadelphia must have been quite the spectacle. (Don't worry, it was a crown of laurels!) Otherwise, google Norton I, Emperor of the United States. Tradition is very important, even in the USA. And no, those titles really would not be that offensive at all.

Comment: @elemtilas You're the man!

Comment: Clearly the correct name of who rules the US without actual power is the Kardashians.  Why would they need more of a title than that?  We already have an Empress (Gladys Knight), kings (Elvis, Chuck Berry), queens (Aretha Franklin), and various other titles.  I'm not convinced that the US really despises such titles.  The founders did -- that's why they banned them.  But in popular opinion?  Not so much.  The US uses celebrities to take the place of British royalty and nobility.  I.e. to be the target of gossip.

Comment: They called him [Emperor of the United States and Protector of Mexico, Norton I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vE40NPNhWlk).  Yep, there was one !

Comment: According to the original interpretation o the Constitution of the United States of America,this position already exists. The most powerful, powerless position was SUPPOSED to be the president, as Head of State. This person signed bills into law, but did not initiate or pass them. The person was supposedly a puppet of Congress - rubber stamping only, but ultimately the chief overseer of Congress.

Comment: @JustinThyme -- The founders also made the President Commander-in-Chief of the military, with the power to temporarily nationalize the local militia.  And they chose their most successful general for the job.

Comment: @Jasper Note there was never the provision nor the intention to have a national standing army. The state militias were intended to be the only armed forces. Even in 1812, the Americans invaded Canada with a state militia, not a national force.

Comment: I think we use the term "Kardashians."

Answer (score 1):

Introducing royalty without giving them powers makes little sense. There are plenty of royalty who *retained* their title and lost all power, but doing it the other way around sounds strange.

Generally there is a distinction between the [head of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_of_state) and the [head of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_of_government). Some democracies have unified both jobs in one person, others have traditional royalty as head of state and a democratically elected head of government, or both head of state and head of government democratically elected.
Unfortunately, president **is** the traditional title for a head of state, with [prime minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_minister) or [chancellor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor) for the head of government.

So you are left with not-quite-fitting names. What you make it will depend on how and why the head of state was introduced into the system.

- [CEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_executive_officer)
- [Princeps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeps)
- [Chairman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chairman)
- [Dear Leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kim_Jong-il%27s_titles)
- [Poet Laureate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poet_laureate)
- Hereditary Secretary of State for Protocol

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'm looking for. "Not-quite-fitting" names - exactly the point